# make a usb 3.0 type B out of two micro usb cables?

Tags: usb

I am in a place where I desperately need a USB 3.0 Micro B cable and can't get one.

Is it possible to use two Micro USB cables to establish a USB 3.0 B connection? The idea is to use one regular Micro USB cable for charging and one for data transfer. As far as I can see, the micro USB 3.0 port on my HDD simply contains two identical Micro USB ports with 5 pins each.

One Micro USB cable fits fine into the Micro USB 3.0 port and does power on the hard drive (I've tried it). Of course, the second Micro USB cable would have to be cut to fit into the port. I plan to connect to two USB ports on my computer. Will this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this will not work, for a few reasons.

First off, the pin out. There are actually 9 pins on USB3, and they're located in a different formation than regular USB Micro. See the picture below:

[image]

You can notice that it's not an exact copy on both sides, only on the left side. The other side has only a few pins.

The other thing is that USB 3 is rated for 4.5Gbps, while USB 2.0 is rated to 450Mbps. This will also cause incompatibilities if you try to use a home-made cable.

On most devices, you can use a regular USB 2.0 cable, and get away with the slower speed. Below is a USB 3.0 A cable end, with the pin outs explained:

[image]

The bottom row of pins is for compatibility with USB 2.0; the other 5 pins are for USB 3.0